# chromium os on rpi3 is not supporting video streaming nor I can watch live or other videos on Chrome except for YouTube

Tags: pi-3b+, chromium, google-chrome, chrome-os

[image: Video not supported by chrome]
I have installed chromium os on rpi3 b+ and while Playing any live video or any other video except on YouTube it's showing video not supported what should I do to fix this issue please help

Comment: This may be because youtube uses h.264 encoded video, which the pi supports, but there are other formats it does not.

Comment: So what to do in order to support other type of videos

Comment: You'd have to find out what they are, but chances are you are out of luck if that is the reason.

Comment: Maybe it's an issue with hardware acceleration that isn't used by chromium? `omxplayer` will use hardware acceleration.